# Create MongoDB Arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to Mongodb.

I have a form textarea with three types of properties.

```
 "Jobs[]" value ="1"
 "Jobs[]" value ="2"
 "Jobs[]" value ="3"
```

But my Schema looks like this:

```
 name: String,
 location: String,
 Jobs: String
```

How can I insert those multiple jobs from my html to my Schema without creating Jobs1, Jobs2 and Jobs3?

Thank you

If it helps, I'm using express, nodejs and mongoose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var JobSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  location: String,
  jobs: [{
    value: Number,
    title: String
  }]
});
```

You can set the Jobs to be an Array within your Schema. When you do find() in mongoose, it will return an array of Jobs that you can loop.

Comment: Thank you! It was easier than expected